# python-redsys Redirect the user-agent with post method

Tags: python, django, payment-processing

i use python-redsys : https://pypi.org/project/python-redsys/

I'm stuck at the step **4. Communication step**

This is my view :

```
@login_required
def redsys_start(request):

    secret_key = DS_SECRET_KEY
    client = RedirectClient(secret_key)

    parameters = {
    "merchant_code": DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE,
    "terminal": DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL,
    "transaction_type": STANDARD_PAYMENT,
    "currency": EUR,
    "order": "000000001",
    "amount": D("10.56489").quantize(D(".01"), ROUND_HALF_UP),
    "merchant_data": "test merchant data",
    "merchant_name": "Example Commerce",
    "titular": "Example Ltd.",
    "product_description": "Products of Example Commerce",
    "merchant_url": reverse('front:shop_cart_payment_callback'),
    }

    args = client.prepare_request(parameters)
    print(f"args =  {args}")
    context = {'args': args, 'BANK_PAIEMENT_URL': BANK_PAIEMENT_URL}

    # STEP 3
    args = client.prepare_request(parameters)
```

What i have to do after that fo redirect my customer to the red sys payement system ?

- If i try to redirect it with parameters redsys refuse because it is with get method
- If i try to make a form with args redsys give me an error SIS0431 (json Ds_MerchantParameters issue)

That is wahat the doc say :

**4. Communication step**

Redirect the user-agent to the corresponding Redsys' endpoint using the post parameters given in the previous step.

After the payment process is finished, Redsys will respond making a request to the merchant_url defined in step 2.

**5. Create and check the response**

Create the response object using the received parameters from Redsys. The method create_response() throws a ValueError in case the received signature is not equal to the calculated one using the given merchant_parameters. This normally means that the response is not coming from Redsys or that it has been compromised.

**EDIT**
As requested my args variable content :

```
args = {'Ds_SignatureVersion': 'HMAC_SHA256_V1', 'Ds_MerchantParameters': b'SOMETHING', 'Ds_Signature': b'SOMETHING'}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Redsys, but usually you must call the Redsys endpoint using their api and `return HttpResponseRedirect(...)` to the browser (i.e. the user-agent)

Comment: Hi, thank for reply.
Do you read what i have tried ?
You tell me "but usually you must call the Redsys endpoint using their api"
But its clearly what i dont know how to do.
If i use return HttpResponseRedirect(...) the param are in get but redsys need i used post method

Comment: The documentation is not the clearest ;-) It says to redirect _using_ the post parameters from step 3, which I am interpreting to mean that the `args` you're getting from `client.prepare_request(...)` will contain parameters that you'll need for your HttpResponseRedirect call.. Can you edit your question and add what is inside `args`?

Comment: @thebjorn its done ! Thanks for your help

Comment: If you look at Figure 4 in section 6.3.1.1 of the documentation (https://hub-i.redsys.es:16443/psd2-doc/DOC_TPP_v.1.8.5_bankinter_vIngles.pdf), it indicates that the url you send to the HttpResponseRedirect should have a `?state=X` parameter, where `X` is (I'm assuming) the state parameter from somewhere inside `Ds_MerchantParameters`. As I mentioned, I've never used redsys (and the English translation of the docs is not the best)...